# Data recover/transfer from a disk image

Tags: data-recovery, data-transfer, file-permissions

**Situation.** I have a `.img` disk image file obtained from a `.vmdk` file via a virtualbox conversion, the latter being created by an Android 4.4.2 emulator. I'm trying to recover some app data and transfer it to a new, working, .img file.

**What I did.** I extracted APKs and copied app data folders (com.devname.appname) from/to the `/data/data` directory. I did that using a file manager and via Ubuntu terminal. I also attempted to copy the folders to `/Android/data`. Although `cp -ar` retains files permissions and ownership, that was of no use after the import into the working image.

**The problem (and a workaround).** When the APKs are installed, a new uid (in the 10000 group) is generated for them. These values are unknown when I import the data folders, hence they are destroyed at phone boot. A log in `/data/system/uiderrors.txt` confirms this. The only way I could make it work was to install the APK, run the app so that the new data folders are created with a proper uid, replace those folders with old ones and fix ownership and permissions accordingly (for every app). This turned out to be effective, but it's a very tedious and error-prone process.

Is there a proper way to achieve this result?

Probably noteworthy:

- Folders are copied after the APK is installed. The APK won't install if folders are there already.
- Original image has some Android data corrupted, so it cannot be mounted in the emulator. `loop mount` works properly, though.
- I didn't modify `packages.list` and `packages.xml` files (should I?).

Comment: This problem exists even for popular/common backup-restore apps such as Titanium Backup; I know of no way to rectify it. +1 and would like to see a solution as well. It would be of less significance after Android 8.x though - now the name of APK folders are hashed too so you can't figure that part out either.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that change in Oreo, good to know. I was also wondering  how backup apps and ADB `backup`/`restore` commands handle file permissions.